# How does EXISTS/NOT EXISTS work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I understand how to write queries using EXISTS. For example, the two following queries are identical:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id in (SELECT manager_id
                      FROM employees);

SELECT last_name
FROM employees e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM employees em
              WHERE em.manager_id = e.employee_id);
```

What I don't understand is the logic behind the `EXISTS` clause. I don't understand how this query is equivalent to the other query that uses `IN` instead.

Please explain the logic behind the `EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can translate `EXISTS` and `IN` into English.

The list of managers:

```
(SELECT manager_id FROM employees)
```

The list of employees, whose `id` is in the list of managers:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE employee_id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM employees)
```

The list of employees, which have a manager, or "for which a manager exists", or "for which a record in table employees exists that has the id that fits to the column `manager_id` of the employee we are currently looking at:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees e
 WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT *
         FROM employees em
        WHERE e.employee_id = em.manager_id
       );
```

Logically, your query loops through all employees, and checks for each employee if there is a matching manager in the same table.

EDIT:
By the way, you'll find many recommendations to use only `EXISTS` or `IN`, and one would be faster than the other one. That has been the case many years ago, but nowadays both queries run with the same speed. Oracle even might translate one syntax into the other one.

Likewise, there are many rumours to use `... IN (SELECT 1 ...` instead of `... IN (SELECT * ...`, that is simply wrong, too.

However, the outer query should use only the columns you need, especially if you need only the `employee_id` or another column that is included in the index.